# Indicating the statistically significant difference in bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

I use a bar graph to indicate the data of each group. Some of these bars differ significantly from each other. How can I indicate the significant difference in the bar plot?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
menMeans   = (5, 15, 30, 40)
menStd     = (2, 3, 4, 5)
ind = np.arange(4)    # the x locations for the groups
width=0.35
p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width=width, color='r', yerr=menStd)
plt.xticks(ind+width/2., ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') )
```

I am aiming for

[image]

Comment: Are the only comparisons to be made locally adjacent? That is, do you only want to show the difference between `(A,B) (B,C) (C,D)` but not `(A,C)`?

Comment: No, I would like to make a comparison between all possible pairs.

Comment: It might be hard to show this on the chart, especially if there are a large number of items. If you have N=10, items there are 45 different pairwise comparisons! It seems like you could display your pairwise p values on a matrix instead. Would this work?

Comment: Are you just trying to achieve the plot attached, or do you really want a matrix as @Hooked suggested?

Comment: Most of the time one would not need to compare all the possible pairs. As in the above case, comparing (A,C) or (A,D) or (B,D) would not give any new information. So ideally, I would like to compare selected pairs, say in one case it can be (A,B), (B,C) and (C,D) (as above) and in case it can be (A,B),(A,C) and (A,D).

Comment: @Hooked, I agree that a matrix make more sense if there are 10 or so bars. However, in my case I have mostly 3 or 4 bars, so the number of comparisons is not an issue. Further bars convey information about mean, range, more easily. However, if comparing all pairs is difficult I would accept a solution that compare only the adjacent pairs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've done a couple of things here that I suggest when working with complex plots. Pull out the custom formatting into a dictionary, it makes life simple when you want to change a parameter - and you can pass this dictionary to multiple plots. I've also written a custom function to `annotate` the itervalues, as a bonus it can annotate between `(A,C)` if you really want to (I stand by my comment that this isn't the right visual approach however). It may need some tweaking once the data changes but this should put you on the right track.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
menMeans   = (5, 15, 30, 40)
menStd     = (2, 3, 4, 5)
ind  = np.arange(4)    # the x locations for the groups
width= 0.7
labels = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

# Pull the formatting out here
bar_kwargs = {'width':width,'color':'y','linewidth':2,'zorder':5}
err_kwargs = {'zorder':0,'fmt':None,'linewidth':2,'ecolor':'k'}  #for matplotlib >= v1.4 use 'fmt':'none' instead

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, **bar_kwargs)
ax.errs = plt.errorbar(ind, menMeans, yerr=menStd, **err_kwargs)


# Custom function to draw the diff bars

def label_diff(i,j,text,X,Y):
    x = (X[i]+X[j])/2
    y = 1.1*max(Y[i], Y[j])
    dx = abs(X[i]-X[j])

    props = {'connectionstyle':'bar','arrowstyle':'-',\
                 'shrinkA':20,'shrinkB':20,'linewidth':2}
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(X[i],y+7), zorder=10)
    ax.annotate('', xy=(X[i],y), xytext=(X[j],y), arrowprops=props)

# Call the function
label_diff(0,1,'p=0.0370',ind,menMeans)
label_diff(1,2,'p<0.0001',ind,menMeans)
label_diff(2,3,'p=0.0025',ind,menMeans)


plt.ylim(ymax=60)
plt.xticks(ind, labels, color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very informative. I just change `ax.annotate(text, xy=(X[i],y+7), zorder=10)` to `ax.annotate(text, xy=(x,y+7), zorder=10)` to make the p-values centered.

Comment: @imsc That's what I used at first, but that is the location of the left side of the text block - not the center of the text block. To me it seems that that are slightly off-center with that placement. Either way, I hope you see how you can tweak away!

Comment: Oh yeah, I also put `ha='center'` in `annotate`.

Answer (score 29):

The answer above inspired me to write a small but flexible function myself:

```
def barplot_annotate_brackets(num1, num2, data, center, height, yerr=None, dh=.05, barh=.05, fs=None, maxasterix=None):
    """ 
    Annotate barplot with p-values.

    :param num1: number of left bar to put bracket over
    :param num2: number of right bar to put bracket over
    :param data: string to write or number for generating asterixes
    :param center: centers of all bars (like plt.bar() input)
    :param height: heights of all bars (like plt.bar() input)
    :param yerr: yerrs of all bars (like plt.bar() input)
    :param dh: height offset over bar / bar + yerr in axes coordinates (0 to 1)
    :param barh: bar height in axes coordinates (0 to 1)
    :param fs: font size
    :param maxasterix: maximum number of asterixes to write (for very small p-values)
    """

    if type(data) is str:
        text = data
    else:
        # * is p < 0.05
        # ** is p < 0.005
        # *** is p < 0.0005
        # etc.
        text = ''
        p = .05

        while data < p:
            text += '*'
            p /= 10.

            if maxasterix and len(text) == maxasterix:
                break

        if len(text) == 0:
            text = 'n. s.'

    lx, ly = center[num1], height[num1]
    rx, ry = center[num2], height[num2]

    if yerr:
        ly += yerr[num1]
        ry += yerr[num2]

    ax_y0, ax_y1 = plt.gca().get_ylim()
    dh *= (ax_y1 - ax_y0)
    barh *= (ax_y1 - ax_y0)

    y = max(ly, ry) + dh

    barx = [lx, lx, rx, rx]
    bary = [y, y+barh, y+barh, y]
    mid = ((lx+rx)/2, y+barh)

    plt.plot(barx, bary, c='black')

    kwargs = dict(ha='center', va='bottom')
    if fs is not None:
        kwargs['fontsize'] = fs

    plt.text(*mid, text, **kwargs)
```

which allows me to get some nice annotations relatively simple, e.g.:

```
heights = [1.8, 2, 3]
bars = np.arange(len(heights))

plt.figure()
plt.bar(bars, heights, align='center')
plt.ylim(0, 5)
barplot_annotate_brackets(0, 1, .1, bars, heights)
barplot_annotate_brackets(1, 2, .001, bars, heights)
barplot_annotate_brackets(0, 2, 'p < 0.0075', bars, heights, dh=.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using matplotlib and seeking boxplot annotation, use my code as a function:

## statistical annotation

```
def AnnoMe(x1, x2, ARRAY, TXT):
    y, h, col = max(max(ARRAY[x1-1]),max(ARRAY[x2-1])) + 2, 2, 'k'
    plt.plot([x1, x1, x2, x2], [y, y+h, y+h, y], lw=1.5, c=col)
    plt.text((x1+x2)*.5, y+h, TXT, ha='center', va='bottom', color=col)
```

where 'x1' and 'x2' are two columns you want to compare, 'ARRAY' is the list of lists you are using for illustrating the boxplot. And, 'TXT' is your text like p-value or significant/not significant in string format.

Accordingly, call it with:

```
AnnoMe(1, 2, MyArray, "p-value=0.02")
```

Answer (score 2):

### Grouped bar plot from pandas dataframe

#### Annotate significant difference between bars

I have modified the solution of @cheersmate in order to receive in input also pandas dataframes. This function is tested with `matplotlib 3.5.1`

```
def annotate_barplot_dataframe(bar0, bar1, text, patches, dh=0.2):
    """Annotate a grouped barplot from a pandas dataframe
    An annotation is added to the figure from bar0 to bar1

    Args:
        bar0 (int): index of first bar
        bar1 (int): index of second bar
        text (string): what to write on the annotation
        patches (matplotlib.patches): data source
        df (float): height of the annotation bar
    """
    patches.sort(key=lambda x: x.xy[0])
    left = patches[bar0]
    right = patches[bar1]

    y = max(left._height, right._height) + dh

    l_bbox = left.get_bbox()
    l_mid = l_bbox.x1 - left._width / 2

    r_bbox = right.get_bbox()
    r_mid = r_bbox.x1 - right._width / 2

    barh = 0.07
    # lower-left, upper-left, upper-right, lower-right
    barx = [l_mid, l_mid, r_mid, r_mid]
    bary = [
        y,
        y + barh,
        y + barh,
        y,
    ]
    plt.plot(barx, bary, c="black")
    kwargs = dict(ha="center", va="bottom")
    mid = ((l_mid + r_mid) / 2, y + 0.01)
    plt.text(*mid, text, **kwargs)

def prepare_df(filename):
    """load filename is exists and prepare it for the plot

    Args:
        filename (string): must be a .xlsx file

    Returns:
        pandas.df: grouped dataframe
    """
    assert filename.endswith("xlsx"), "Check file extension"

    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=0, usecols="H:W", engine="openpyxl")
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError(e)
    # Columnkey is the variable by which we want to group
    # e.g. in this example columnskey's entries have 3 different values
    grouped = df.groupby(df["Columnkey"])

    df_group1 = grouped.get_group(1)
    df_group2 = grouped.get_group(2)
    df_group3 = grouped.get_group(3)

    g = pd.concat(
        [
            df_group1.mean().rename("C1"),
            df_group2.mean().rename("C2"),
            df_group3.mean().rename("C3"),
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    return g
```

So the input to the function should look something like this.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "Data.xlsx"
    dataframe = prepare_df(filename)
    width = 0.7
    ax = dataframe.plot.bar(width=width, figsize=(9, 2))
    # this plot will group in sets of 3
    patches = ax.patches._axes.axes.containers[0].patches
    patches.extend(ax.patches._axes.axes.containers[1].patches)
    patches.extend(ax.patches._axes.axes.containers[2].patches)
    annotate_barplot_dataframe(0, 1, "*", patches, 0.1)
    annotate_barplot_dataframe(1, 2, "*", patches, 0.1)

    plt.savefig(fname="filename.pdf", bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.show()
```

The outcome will save to disk a picture like 
[image: example]