# Indicating the statistically significant difference in bar graph USING R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

This is a repeat of a question originally asked here: [Indicating the statistically significant difference in bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517986/indicating-the-statistically-significant-difference-in-bar-graph) but asked for R instead of python.

My question is very simple. I want to produce barplots in R, using ggplot2 if possible, with an indication of significant difference between the different bars, e.g. produce something like this. I have had a search around but can't find another question asking exactly the same thing.

[image: bar plot showing error bars and sig. diff marking beween bars]

Comment: So only adjacent columns? No p value for A-C, B-D or A-D?

Comment: Annoyingly enough (not your fault), something in my local firewall is killing your image. Can you post a link?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Image here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3I6El.jpg

Comment: I would like an easy option to do A-C/A-D etc. as well in a way that isn't too fiddly, not sure if I'm expecting too much though

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `geom_path()` and `annotate()` to get similar result. For this example you have to determine suitable position yourself. In `geom_path()` four numbers are provided to get those small ticks for connecting lines.

```
df<-data.frame(group=c("A","B","C","D"),numb=c(12,24,36,48))
g<-ggplot(df,aes(group,numb))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
g+geom_path(x=c(1,1,2,2),y=c(25,26,26,25))+
  geom_path(x=c(2,2,3,3),y=c(37,38,38,37))+
  geom_path(x=c(3,3,4,4),y=c(49,50,50,49))+
  annotate("text",x=1.5,y=27,label="p=0.012")+
  annotate("text",x=2.5,y=39,label="p<0.0001")+
  annotate("text",x=3.5,y=51,label="p<0.0001")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - OK this is a little fiddly, but this is what I want! I guess there's no readily available, general (automatic!) way to do it

Comment: Oof, any way to control the geom_path when using faceting?

Comment: @JimBo Then you will need a data frame for the geom_path() values and in this data frame you have to include also the column with the same name and levels as will be used for the faceting.

Answer (score 19):

I know that this is an old question and the answer by Didzis Elferts already provides one solution for the problem. But I recently created a ggplot-extension that simplifies the whole process of adding significance bars: [ggsignif](https://github.com/Artjom-Metro/ggsignif)

Instead of tediously adding the `geom_path` and `annotate` to your plot you just add a single layer `geom_signif`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("versicolor", "virginica")), 
              map_signif_level=TRUE)
```

[image: Boxplot with significance bar]

Full documentation of the package is available at [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/index.html).

Comment: Is there anything like this but for scatter plots and regression lines?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein, checkout https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot

Comment: I would like to use chisq.test but when calculating it with geom_signif I get different results compared to doing it myself. Is there a possibility to just provide precalculated p-values to the function?

Comment: Yes, just set the `annotation` parameter. The second example on https://const-ae.github.io/ggsignif/#example shows you how you could do this :)

Answer (score 5):

I used the suggested method from above, but I found the annotate function easier for making lines than the geom_path function. Just use "segment" instead of "text". You have to break things up by segment and define starting and ending x and y values for each line segment.

example for making 3 lines segments:

```
annotate("segment", x=c(1,1,2),xend=c(1,2,2), y= c(125,130,130), yend=c(130,130,125))
```