# error with adding geom_path to boxplot using ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I intend to create a boxplot and highlight the significance level of pairwise comparisons. This has been dealt in a [previous post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958159/indicating-the-statistically-significant-difference-in-bar-graph-using-r)

When I do the same for my data-set, I get the following error:

```
 "Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: x, y"
```

Here's an example data-set to illustrate the problem -

```
data1<-data.frame(island = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "A"), count = c(2, 5, 12, 2, 3))
g1<-ggplot(data1) +  geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(island), y = count)) 
g1 + geom_path(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2), y = c(25, 26, 26, 25))
```

I get the error while running the third line of the code, while the boxplot turns out alright. I suspect I'm missing out on something very trivial, but I'm unable to catch it. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: +1 for asking your first question with a small test data set, what you have tried, posting the exact error message, and the expected results!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't have an explicit `data` argument in `geom_path`, data from the `data` argument in `ggplot` is 'inherited' to `geom_path`. The machinery then chokes when it finds out that the length of the x and y variables in 'data1' differs from the length of the x and y vectors in the `geom_path` call. Try to create a separate data frame for `geom_path` and use the `data` argument:

```
data2 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2), y = c(25, 26, 26, 25))

ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = factor(island), y = count)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_path(data = data2, aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer, because it is too long to be a comment, but it is meant as a supplement to the already accepted answer.

In a similar situation I tried employing `geom_path` to a colored barplot, but got this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Species' not found
```

Then it turns out that the `fill` option should be turned "off", otherwise it follows the one in the preceding `ggplot` call, which asks for the `Species` column and leads such error.

```
## ## Load the libraries
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

## ## Make toy data
data1 <- data.table(iris)[,list(value=Petal.Length,Species)]

## ## Draw the bars
p <- ggplot(data=data1,aes(x=Species,y=value,fill=Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL)

## ## Add lines and an annotation
y1 <- data1[Species=="setosa",max(value)]*1.02
y2 <- y3 <- data1[,max(value)]*1.05
y4 <- data1[Species=="virginica",max(value)]*1.005
data2 <- data.frame(x.=c(1,1,3,3),y.=c(y1,y2,y3,y4))

p <- p +
  ## geom_path(data=data2,aes(x=x.,y=y.)) + # the line that cause the ERROR
  geom_path(data=data2,aes(x=x.,y=y.,fill=NULL)) + # the corrected line
  annotate("text",x=2,y=y3,label="***")
p
```

[image]